# AJAX Rest get currency format

Tags: rest, ajax, api

I have a 'Price' column of type Currency, but the data in the returned ajax object is just a number.

Is the currency format somehow available?

Returned data

```
....
Modified:"2017-01-20T14:50:42Z"

OData__UIVersionString:"1.0"

Price:1234

ParentList:Object

....
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we are retrieving values for `Currency` column, it only returns its value in Numeric format but doesn't returns Currency Type.

As we know a Currency column can be set to contain only one type of currency so  first retrieve Currency Type by its column property `CurrencyLocaleId`.

```
http://siteURL/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListB')/fields/getByTitle('CurrencyCol')?$select=CurrencyLocaleId
```

The above REST call return 4 digit LCID (Locale ID) which is universal for each type of locale e.g. 1033 is for English - United States so its currency would be USD.

You can find complete list of LCID in the below link.

[LCID list](http://www.vbsedit.com/html/882ca1eb-81b6-4a73-839d-154c6440bf70.asp)